# React Native(Expo) SecureStore getItemAsync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm Using "expo-secure-store" to store JWT Token. when I try to get the data first it returns nothing and then the token.

my code:

```
const [api, ApiReply] = React.useState("");
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

const [token, setToken] = React.useState("");

const clickHandler = () => {
    
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("secure_token").then((token) => setToken(token));
    console.log(token);
    
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    
    var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: myHeaders,
    };

    fetch("http://193.119.10.206:3000/auth/user/8", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => ApiReply(JSON.parse(result)))
        .catch((d) => {
            alert("500");
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));

};


React.useEffect(() => { 
    clickHandler();
}, [api])
```

I need the token when it's rendered. is there any solution or any alternative way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways you can do this:

1. move everything inside the `then` closure. This will wait for your get async function to finish before doing anything with the token.

   ```
    const clickHandler = () => {   
      SecureStore.getItemAsync("secure_token").then((token) => {
        setToken(token);
        console.log(token);
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: myHeaders,
        };
        fetch("http://193.119.10.206:3000/auth/user/8", requestOptions)
         .then((response) => response.text())
         .then((result) => ApiReply(JSON.parse(result)))
         .catch((d) => {
           alert("500");
         })
         .finally(() => setLoading(false));
         });
     };
   ```
2. Use `await` instead:

   ```
    const clickHandler = async () => {
    const token = SecureStore.getItemAsync("secure_token");
    setToken(token);
    console.log(token);

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: myHeaders,
    };

    fetch("http://193.119.10.206:3000/auth/user/8", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => ApiReply(JSON.parse(result)))
        .catch((d) => {
            alert("500");
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
   ```

   };
3. utilize useEffect:

   ```
    const clickHandler = ()=>{
       SecureStore.getItemAsync("secure_token").then((token) => setToken(token));
    }
   ```

   `useEffect(()=>{ if(token !== null) { //call fetch } },[token])`